# How do I import iGLU library to xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opengl-es

If anyone doesn't know, iGLU

http://code.google.com/p/iphone-glu/

is a GLU library for iphone.

I can't seem to import the library to my project, it says to to run the following command but i get errors:

make ARCH=armv6 PLATFORM=iphoneOS

Has anyone get iGLU working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need editing the file `iGLU/configs/darwin-iphone` and modify it so that it reflects your Xcode environment.

In my case I had to change the lines:

```
 GCC_VERSION = xxx
 IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = xxx
```

to

```
GCC_VERSION = 4.2
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 4.2
```

and then exec make as you stated.

Comment: Hmm, getting errors too. Do I have to edit only those two lines? What are the other things?