# iGLU library compile errors

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I want to use the glu library for opengl in xcode.  There is a thread about it here:

[How do I import iGLU library to xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484593/how-do-i-import-iglu-library-to-xcode?answertab=active#tab-top)

Unfortunately I am getting errors with this.  I tried to post a followup question to that thread, but it would not let me and someone deleted it when I posted my question as an "answer".  So all I know to do is post an entirely separate question:

I am trying this, and I changed the config file as described in the thread. But I still got errors. By changing the config file to not even put a version number for the gcc, it uses the default gcc in my bin directory. I also tried having it access 'llvm-gcc-4.2' since that was another binary in `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin`.

But now I get compile errors indicating that it can't find gl.h.

> include/glu.h:34:29: error: OpenGLES/ES1/gl.h: No such file or
>   directory In file included from libutil/error.c:33: include/glu.h:157:
>   error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘attribute’ before
>   ‘gluCheckExtension’ . . . etc.

How do I fix that? Anyone know? Thanks Bob

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions you reference to alter the darwin-iphone config file include the instruction to set `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 4.2`. This will cause the build process to look for the OpenGLES/ES1/gl.h header file in 4.2 version SDK. You probably don't have that version of the SDK installed. If you have the latest release version of Xcode, you should have the SDK for iOS 5 installed, and iGLU will compile if you use `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 5.0` in the config file.

Comment: Thanks!  I was using the same deployment target as in my app.  I guess they are slightly different things because in the app you build against the 5.0 SDK but the deployment target is whatever OS version you want to support.

Comment: Do you or anyone know how to handle the fact that this build only creates a single architecture?  An app can support multiple (v6, v7) architectures in a single app can't it?  How would you incorporate iGlu into an app like that?  Just include both versions?